# Destroying a field which gives error in Content Enrichment Web Service

Tags: 2013, column, delete, content-enrichment

I’m writing a Content Enrichment Web Service that is used as an extension to the Content Processing component in my Search Service Application. The web service runs as expected at localhost. I have no problem adding it to my Search Service Application through PowerShell (when all crawl activity are idle).

When running the full crawl I get readable errors in the ULS, but am unable to locate the field mentioned. Searching term store, site columns and the TaxonomyHiddenList gives no clue either. I want to locate the field and destroy it forever. The question is **where** the following field lives?

> `Error: [ContentEnrichment] The field name 'owstaxIdNøkkelord' is not valid.`

## ULS log error

```
11/21/2013 12:47:23.07  NodeRunnerContent1-e7775856-eb2 (0x0D18)    0x239C  Search                          Content Processing              ai89o   High        
ContentIntegrationEngine : Evaluation of flow Microsoft.CrawlerFlow failed. 
Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Operator graph Microsoft.CrawlerFlow failed validation   
Status: Error, Messages:   
[Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Operators.BuiltIn.SubFlow.SubFlow(
subFlowName="Microsoft.CrawlerContentEnrichmentSubFlow",
subFlowInputs=Null,
subFlowOutputs=Null,
inputOutputMap={},
label="ContentEnrichment",
errorTarget=Null,
additionalSuccessors=Null)] 
Error: [ContentEnrichment] The field name 'owstaxIdNøkkelord' is not valid. 
Field names can only contain English letters, digits, the underline character '_', and the punctuation mark '.'. 
The name must start with a letter and cannot end with a punctuation mark.  
[Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Operators.BuiltIn.SubFlow.SubFlow(
subFlowName="Microsoft.CrawlerAlertsDataGenerationSubFlow",
subFlowInputs=Null,
subFlowOutputs=Null,
inputOutputMap={},
label="AlertsDataGenerator",
errorTarget=Null,
additionalSuccessors=Null)] 
Warning: [Alerts.RemoveFieldListBeforeAlerts] 
The field 'FieldList' is marked for removal, but cannot be found in the input.     
at Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Component.ContentIntegrationEngine.ThrowValidationError(OperatorFlow flow, GraphStatusMessages status)     
at Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Component.ContentIntegrationEngine.PrepareFlow(OperatorFlow flow, FlowEvaluationConfig flowConfig, CieLogWriter& lw, EvaluationConfig& config, ICallbackManager& callbackManager)     
at Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Component.ContentIntegrationEngine.ExecuteFlowInternal(OperatorFlow flow, Boolean debug, FlowEvaluationConfig flowConfig, Boolean start, Boolean isNested)     
at Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Component.ContentIntegrationEngine.ExecuteFlowAndWait(OperatorFlow flow, Boolean debug, FlowEvaluationConfig config)     
at Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Component.ContentIntegrationEngine.ExecuteFlow(String name, Boolean debug, FlowEvaluationConfig config)
```

## The [Web Service source code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163982.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.ContentProcessingEnrichment;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.ContentProcessingEnrichment.PropertyTypes;

namespace ContentProcessingEnrichmentService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "ContentProcessingEnrichmentService" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select ContentProcessingEnrichmentService.svc or ContentProcessingEnrichmentService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class ContentProcessingEnrichmentService : IContentProcessingEnrichmentService
    {
        // Defines the name of the managed property 'Filename'.
        private const string FileNameProperty = "Filename";

        // Defines the name of the managed property 'Author'
        private const string AuthorProperty = "Author";

        // Defines the temporary directory where binary data will be stored.
        private const string TempDirectory = @"C:\Temp";

        // Defines the error code for managed properties with an unexpected type.
        private const int UnexpectedType = 1;

        // Defines the error code for encountering unexpected exceptions.
        private const int UnexpectedError = 2;

        private readonly ProcessedItem processedItemHolder = new ProcessedItem
        {
            ItemProperties = new List<AbstractProperty>()
        };

        public ProcessedItem ProcessItem(Item item)
        {
            processedItemHolder.ErrorCode = 0;
            processedItemHolder.ItemProperties.Clear();
            try
            {
                // Iterate over each property received and locate the two properties we
                // configured the system to send.
                foreach (var property in item.ItemProperties)
                {
                    // Check if this is the author property.
                    if (property.Name.Equals(AuthorProperty, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        var author = property as Property<List<string>>;
                        if (author == null)
                        {
                            // The author property was not of the expected type.
                            // Update the error code and return. 
                            processedItemHolder.ErrorCode = UnexpectedType;
                            return processedItemHolder;
                        }

                        // Adding a new author to the list so it will become searchable.      
                        author.Value.Add("ExampleService");
                        processedItemHolder.ItemProperties.Add(author);
                    }
                    else if (property.Name.Equals(FileNameProperty, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        var filename = property as Property<string>;
                        if (filename == null)
                        {
                            // The file name property was not of the expected type.
                            // Update error code and return.
                            processedItemHolder.ErrorCode = UnexpectedType;
                            return processedItemHolder;
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename.Value))
                        {
                            var fullFilePath = string.Join(char.ToString(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), TempDirectory, filename.Value);
                            if (item.RawData != null)
                            {
                                var outputFile = File.Create(fullFilePath);
                                using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(outputFile))
                                {
                                    writer.Write(item.RawData);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                processedItemHolder.ErrorCode = UnexpectedError;
            }
            return processedItemHolder;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: CEWS running]

## The PowerShell script adding the Content Enrichment Web Service to the Search Service Application

```
    # Create and add your CEWS to IIS, before using this

    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
    {
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
    }

    $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
    $config = New-SPEnterpriseSearchContentEnrichmentConfiguration
    $config.Endpoint = "http://localhost/ContentProcessingEnrichmentService/ContentProcessingEnrichmentService.svc"
    $config.InputProperties = "Author", "Filename"
    $config.OutputProperties = "Author"
    $config.SendRawData = $True
    $config.MaxRawDataSize = 8192
    Set-SPEnterpriseSearchContentEnrichmentConfiguration –SearchApplication $ssa –ContentEnrichmentConfiguration $config

    # To Remove, use this
    #Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchContentEnrichmentConfiguration –SearchApplication $ssa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field seems to be a crawled property  `owstaxIdNøkkelord` that you can delete via *Search Service application* -> *Search Administration* -> *Query and Results* -> *Search Schema*

You will find crawled properties listed on Search Schema page.

See also [how to delete a crawled property](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17437.sharepoint-2010-how-to-delete-crawled-property.aspx)

Comment: Super! A GUI for finding all of my nowegian letters in the crawled properties(æ Æ ø Ø)! Thanks! This was due to an export/import acticvity.

Comment: Leave behind some Norwegian cheese instead of corrupted fields :)